# In android, Can we use conditions to make sure that developer always writes unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, static-analysis, lint, android-lint

In android, how can I make sure that developers always write unit test of each method they wrote? Is there a lint or klint library or custom code to check that, for example If i have written a function, lint should ask in warning that if you have written its unit test or not? Then I create unit test of it and then it removes the warning.

For some methods like `onCreate()` etc we can't write unit tests so we can set it to some other property to ignore the warning when lint asks for it.

Comment: Even if this exists, it's not going to work. Developers will just write useless unit tests if they're forced to write tests.

Comment: otherwise may be they will just skip or forget. what we can do is to encourage them.

Comment: One approach to solve this problem is to run unit tests in your CI pipeline with code coverage. The pipeline must fail if the code coverage is below a threshold value which you define.

Comment: yes that can be a solution but i wanted this to check on compile time. so that developer should know immediately after writing the function.

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/studio/test#view_test_coverage